# Problem with installing gym ( Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error)

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, openai-gym

I wanted to install gym in my pc, so I tried
`pip install gym`

```
everything went fine till 
Collecting gym
  Using cached gym-0.18.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in c:\users\csc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from gym) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.5.0,>=1.4.0 in c:\users\csc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from gym) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\csc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from gym) (1.5.4)
Collecting cloudpickle<1.7.0,>=1.2.0
  Using cached cloudpickle-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting Pillow<=7.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz (39.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\csc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyglet<=1.5.0,>=1.4.0->gym) (0.18.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
  Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
```

but got a big error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\csc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CSC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xwue2xuw\\pillow_70b2da91b4b24fe8a3af6f2412c19502\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CSC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xwue2xuw\\pillow_70b2da91b4b24fe8a3af6f2412c19502\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\CSC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-rj69kfwz'
       cwd: C:\Users\CSC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xwue2xuw\pillow_70b2da91b4b24fe8a3af6f2412c19502\
  Complete output (172 lines):
  C:\Users\CSC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xwue2xuw\pillow_70b2da91b4b24fe8a3af6f2412c19502\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext


  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\CSC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xwue2xuw\pillow_70b2da91b4b24fe8a3af6f2412c19502\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\csc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\csc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\csc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\CSC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xwue2xuw\pillow_70b2da91b4b24fe8a3af6f2412c19502\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\CSC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xwue2xuw\pillow_70b2da91b4b24fe8a3af6f2412c19502\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
```

I don't know why is this happening I have pillow installed with out any problem but not this.
I even tried installing it by git but got same error.
I also edited the logs for making it short thinking most of it is present
I have :

- windows-10
- python -3.9
- pip-20.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python 3.8 that fix this issue. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The latest gym version is 0.18.0 which is compatible with the older versions of Pillow and not with the latest Pillow 8.0.1. Python 3.9 on the other hand does not support older versions of Pillow. So, please wait till newer version of gym, which is compatible with Pillow 8.0.1 is released or till some newer version of Pillow is released with support for the older versions of gym. Sorry, but no solution till today.
Regards

Comment: but cant i use older version of pillow gym and python to make it work

Comment: plz telll which is the best version i can work with